# Show or Preview default 30 days of data until user select date range from slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to show default last 30 days of data until user do not choose a date range from a date slicer ?

I have a column "DateRange" for slicer.

Thanks in advance !

Thanks & Regards,

Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a default and switch slicers, what you can do is use [Bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks). So you create one bookmark with the Default filter, then the other without it. You can then add the bookmarks to a button that you can click on and switch between the two. You can also set visuals to show and hide in a bookmark, so for example hide the data slicer in the 'default' view and when you click on the 'date range' the slicer will appear.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction